# Concat data frames and create columns based on value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two data frames that have a zip to city alignment

df_1

```
ZIP   | TERRITORY | SEGMENT  | 
93517 | 1001      | CR1
31625 | 1002      | CR1
89311 | 1002      | CR1
```

df_2

```
ZIP   | TERRITORY | SEGMENT  | 
93517 | 2001      | CR2
31625 | 2002      | CR2
72844 | 2003      | CR2
```

I want to concat these two data frames to look like this

df_final

```
ZIP   |CR1_TERRITORY  |CR2_TERRITORY  
93517 | 1001          | 2001
31625 | 1002          | 2002
89311 | 1002          | 0
72844 | 0             | 2003
```

I have tried a concating but not sure how to combine so the index is `ZIP` and pull the appropriate territory as needed. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If `df_1` only contains `cr1` segment, and `df_2` only contains `cr2` segments then a [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) would be a route forward:

```
df_final = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer', on='ZIP', suffix=['CR1','CR2'])
```